# Does a MySQL Primary Key on two columns help with queries on the second column?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, many-to-many

I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. Each `Bar` will contain many `Foo`s. `Foo`s can be in multiple `Bar`s but each `Foo` can only be in a given `Bar` once. I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `bar_foos` (
   `bar_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `foo_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( `bar_id` , `foo_id` )
);
```

This should work fine for my many-to-many relationship. My question is, if I want my code to be able to check to see if a `Foo` is in use by any `Bar`s, I.E. to tell the user "This Foo cannot be deleted because it is in use by 5 Bars", does the PRIMARY KEY index help me with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `bar_foos` WHERE `foo_id`=2
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bar_foos` WHERE `foo_id`=2
```

Or, do I need a separate index for the `foo_id` column alone?

Comment: If it's a one-to-many relationship, why do you need a `bar_foos` table? Why not just use `bar.foo_id` (and have an index on that field as well)?

Comment: "Foos can be in multiple Bars but each Foo can only be in a given Bar once." It's not a one-to-many relationship, it's a many-to-many with distinct combinations.

Comment: @Michael: @djacobson got on the nose, I can't do it that way

Comment: Right. Foos and bars, being the generic widgets that they are, are easy to mis-conceptualize. One possible implementation of what you're describing could be course registration - `Each course will contain many students. Students can be in multiple classes but each student can only be in a given class once.`

Comment: @Michael yes, sorry for using generic cutesy terms. The actual items are elements of a WYSIWYG program and I left it out to make it more generic.

Comment: Plus, everyone loves Foo and Bar! XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

"If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index."

Comment: So he needs to reverse his index strategy?

Comment: For that particular query, he'd need another index with foo_id as the only or leftmost column

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if you were searching a phone book where there is an index on last names with a secondary index on the first name. (And this is realy how it is.)

- good - where last_name = 'Smith' and first_name = 'John'
- good - where last_name = 'Smith'
- bad - where first_name = 'John'

'John's can appear on any page in the phone book so it does not narrow it down.

So if you want to use index on first names you would have to 'print a new phone book that ordered names by first name. Or, in a database, create a new index with first names as the first column index.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, No.

On a partial key search, it would only help if the partials are in the order they are in the index.  So, if the key were a three part key and you searched on parts 1 & 2, but not 3, it would help.  If you searched on parts 2 & 3, it would not.

Answer (score 1):

No. Helps on the first or on both.

Comment: PRIMARY is just a unique index. The only reason it has a special name is that some storage engines (e.g. InnoDB) order data on disk by one of the indexes.